# Select first of multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 `<section>`s on a page with the class `.slider` and within these there are several `<article>`s. For the purpose of making these work as tabbed content I want to use jQuery to hide all but the first of each these `<article>`s.

The following:

```
$(".slider > article:not(:first)").hide();
```

hides everything but the first `<article>` in the first `<section>`, I need it to iterate through the three `<section>`s and hide the first in each of these. I assume I need to use `each()` to loop through them, but I can't make anything work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".slider > article:not(:first-child)").hide();
```

If it isn't the first child, you can do this.

```
$(".slider").find("article:not(:first)").hide();
```